# Move Uploaded File Faied - php

Tags: php, mysql, file-upload

I have these errors compiling php

> MOVE UPLOADED FILE FAILED!
>       Array ( [type] => 2 [message] => move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/tmp/phpuFeMBl' to 'upload/horaizontal-hilly-evening.jpg' [file]
>   => /var/www/html/directoryUpload/index.php [line] => 10 )

before that I got an error like >>

> MOVE UPLOADED FILE FAILED!
>       Array ( [type] => 2 [message] => move_uploaded_file() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given [file] =>
>   /var/www/html/directoryUpload/index.php [line] => 9 )

---

I actually need to upload and show some of my projects into my portfolio site as a practice project.

I have the upload folder just near the php file.

php code

```
<?php
$count = 0;
$uploads_dir = 'upload/';

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
    foreach ($_FILES["files"]["name"] as $key => $name) {
      if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$key], 'upload/'.$name)) {
            $count++;
          echo "<P>FILE UPLOADED TO: $target_file</P>";
       } else {
          echo "<P>MOVE UPLOADED FILE FAILED!</P>";
          print_r(error_get_last());
       }     

    }

}
?>
```

HTML code

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Directory Upload using webkidriectory</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="wrap">
            <?php
            if ($count > 0) {
                echo "<p class='msg'>{$count} files uploaded</p>\n\n";
            }
            ?>

            <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <input type="file" name="files[]" id="files" multiple="" directory="" webkitdirectory="" mozdirectory="">
                <input class="button" type="submit" value="Upload" />
            </form>

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should check if the target folder is writable for you executing user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you run your script for example with apache on a debian server it is executed by a user called www-data and group www-data. In that case you should change the owner of your upload folder to www-data with

```
chown www-data:www-data uploads
```

And to be sure that the new owner is allowed to write into you should give him read and write access by

```
chmod 644 uploads
```

I suspect that missing write permissons are the reason for your failing move.

Another simple way but less secure is to change the chmod to 777 regardless of the owner. But this means tha any user may read write and execute that folder.

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        Select image to upload:
        <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
        <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
    } else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, got the answer,
I have just provide enough permission.
sudo chmod -R 0777 /tmp 
and
sudo chmod -R 0777 /var/www
now one single image is in upload folder 
but how may I upload a full directory?
Anyone please let me have some way.

I actually need to upload and show some of my projects into my portfolio site as a practice project. Some help is really needed!

Thanks